# When a notification was clicked , it must be redirected to desired page in IOS

Tags: ios, swift, firebase-cloud-messaging

In FCM notifications when a user clicks on notification it is redirecting to home page but I want to redirect to a specific page other than home page and the app is in foreground. When it was redirected to specific page the app should read the data in the notification and display the data on the page.

Here is the code that represent the above idea but it redirects to home page and nothing is happening(like display data).

> My APPDelegate.class

```
import UIKit
import Firebase
import UserNotifications 

@UIApplicationMain
class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate {  

    var window: UIWindow?
    let gcmMessageIDKey = "gcm.message_id"


    func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {
        // Override point for customization after application launch.
        FirebaseApp.configure()
        Messaging.messaging().delegate = self as! MessagingDelegate
        //Register for notification
        if #available(iOS 10.0, *) {
            // For iOS 10 display notification (sent via APNS)
            UNUserNotificationCenter.current().delegate = self as? UNUserNotificationCenterDelegate

            let authOptions: UNAuthorizationOptions = [.alert, .badge, .sound]
            UNUserNotificationCenter.current().requestAuthorization(
                options: authOptions,
                completionHandler: {_, _ in })
        } else {
            let settings: UIUserNotificationSettings =
                UIUserNotificationSettings(types: [.alert, .badge, .sound], categories: nil)
            application.registerUserNotificationSettings(settings)
        }
        application.registerForRemoteNotifications()
        return true
    }
    func application(_ application: UIApplication, didReceiveRemoteNotification userInfo: [AnyHashable: Any]) {
        // If you are receiving a notification message while your app is in the background,
        // this callback will not be fired till the user taps on the notification launching the application.
        // TODO: Handle data of notification
        // With swizzling disabled you must let Messaging know about the message, for Analytics
        // Messaging.messaging().appDidReceiveMessage(userInfo)
        // Print message ID.
        if let messageID = userInfo[gcmMessageIDKey] {
            print("Message ID: \(messageID)")
        }

        // Print full message.
        print(userInfo)
    }
    func application(_ application: UIApplication, didReceiveRemoteNotification userInfo: [AnyHashable: Any],
                     fetchCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping (UIBackgroundFetchResult) -> Void) {
        // If you are receiving a notification message while your app is in the background,
        // this callback will not be fired till the user taps on the notification launching the application.
        // TODO: Handle data of notification
        // With swizzling disabled you must let Messaging know about the message, for Analytics
        // Messaging.messaging().appDidReceiveMessage(userInfo)
        // Print message ID.
        if let messageID = userInfo[gcmMessageIDKey] {
            print("Message ID: \(messageID)")
        }

        // Print full message.
        print(userInfo)

        completionHandler(UIBackgroundFetchResult.newData)
    }
    // [END receive_message]
    func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFailToRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithError error: Error) {
        print("Unable to register for remote notifications: \(error.localizedDescription)")
    }

    // This function is added here only for debugging purposes and can be removed if swizzling is enabled.
    // If swizzling is disabled then this function must be implemented so that the APNs token can be paired with
    // the FCM registration token.
    func application(_ application: UIApplication, didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken deviceToken: Data) {
        print("APNs token retrieved: \(deviceToken)")

        // With swizzling disabled you must set the APNs token here.
        // Messaging.messaging().apnsToken = deviceToken
    }
}

// [START ios_10_message_handling]
@available(iOS 10, *)
extension AppDelegate : UNUserNotificationCenterDelegate {

    // Receive displayed notifications for iOS 10 devices.
    func userNotificationCenter(_ center: UNUserNotificationCenter,
                                willPresent notification: UNNotification,
                                withCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping (UNNotificationPresentationOptions) -> Void) {
        let userInfo = notification.request.content.userInfo

        // With swizzling disabled you must let Messaging know about the message, for Analytics
        // Messaging.messaging().appDidReceiveMessage(userInfo)
        // Print message ID.
        if let messageID = userInfo[gcmMessageIDKey] {
            print("Message ID: \(messageID)")
        }

        // Print full message.
        print(userInfo)

        // Change this to your preferred presentation option
        completionHandler([.alert, .badge, .sound])
    }

    func userNotificationCenter(_ center: UNUserNotificationCenter,
                                didReceive response: UNNotificationResponse,
                                withCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping () -> Void) {
        let userInfo = response.notification.request.content.userInfo
        // Print message ID.
        if let messageID = userInfo[gcmMessageIDKey] {
            print("Message ID: \(messageID)")
        }

        // Print full message.
        print(userInfo)

        completionHandler()
    }
}
// [END ios_10_message_handling]

extension AppDelegate : MessagingDelegate {
    // [START refresh_token]
    func messaging(_ messaging: Messaging, didRefreshRegistrationToken fcmToken: String) {
        print("Firebase registration token: \(fcmToken)")

        // TODO: If necessary send token to application server.
        // Note: This callback is fired at each app startup and whenever a new token is generated.
    }
    // [END refresh_token]
    // [START ios_10_data_message]
    // Receive data messages on iOS 10+ directly from FCM (bypassing APNs) when the app is in the foreground.
    // To enable direct data messages, you can set Messaging.messaging().shouldEstablishDirectChannel to true.
    func messaging(_ messaging: Messaging, didReceive remoteMessage: MessagingRemoteMessage) {
        print("Received data message: \(remoteMessage.appData)")
    }
    // [END ios_10_data_message]
}
```

Comment: when you will tap on notification banner, `willPresent ` method will call. So you can pass `userInfo` dictionary to another viewController.

Comment: when i tap on notification it is not redirecting to any page

Comment: off course, you need to navigate

Comment: But I ddinot find any solution how to navigate to controller when taping on notification'

Answer (score 12, accepted):

add this code inside `didReceive Response` method like that:

```
func userNotificationCenter(_ center: UNUserNotificationCenter,
                                    didReceive response: UNNotificationResponse,
                                    withCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping () -> Void) {
    let userInfo = response.notification.request.content.userInfo
    // Print message ID.
    if let messageID = userInfo[gcmMessageIDKey] {
        print("Message ID: \(messageID)")
    }

    // Print full message.
    print(userInfo)
    
    let storyBoard: UIStoryboard = UIStoryboard(name: "yourStoryboardName", bundle: nil)
    let presentViewController = storyBoard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "yourViewControllerStoryboardID") as! YourViewController
        
    presentViewController.yourDict = userInfo //pass userInfo data to viewController
    self.window?.rootViewController = presentViewController
    presentViewController.present(presentViewController, animated: true, completion: nil)

    completionHandler()
}
```

Comment: self.present(presentViewController, animated: true, completion: nil)
getting error at these line"Value of type 'AppDelegate' has no member '

Comment: here yourdictt means name of the label

Comment: create dictionary in your viewController, where you want to navigate.

Comment: can we get notifications in. simulator

Comment: In userInfo  I have [AnyHashable("ReceiverPhoneNumber"): 918186982125, AnyHashable("ReceiverId"): WhazKkmykCcoL8hQ38draeL3TEu2, AnyHashable("Amount"): 200, AnyHashable("SenderAutoId"): lKDOvNpTKxNEcP92sPn5, AnyHashable("Name"): Vijayasri, AnyHashable("SenderID"): WhazKkmykCcoL8hQ38draeL3TEu2, AnyHashable("flag"): 1, AnyHashable("SenderName"): Vijayasri, AnyHashable("gcm.message_id"): 0:1523421080189242%d221e6fed221e6fe, AnyHashable("aps"): {
    alert =     {
        body = "Vijayasri requested you to pay $200";
        title = Message;
    };
    sound = default;
}]

Comment: How can I get the Amount field and pass to other view controller . when I tried userInfo.Amount it shows me an error

Comment: `userInfo["Amount"]`

Comment: presentViewController.Amount = userInfo["Amount"] when I use this line it shows  Cannot assign value of type 'Any?' to type 'UILabel!'

Comment: assign `var amount:String?` in `PresentViewController` after that do `presentViewController.Amount = String(describing: userInfo["Amount"])`.And in your `PresentViewController` set label of text as amount.

Comment: you need amount as a String or Int?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/168719/discussion-between-lahari-areti-and-shabbir-ahmad).

Comment: Present View Controller the passed data shows as nil why I am not understanding the problem . Amount shows as nil

Comment: print it `print("\(userInfo["Amount"])")`

Comment: let me know the result

Comment: print("\(userInfo["Amount"])") here I am getting the value

Comment: There must be another instance of yourViewController is created while navigating, debug it and check.

Comment: I'm getting: NSInvalidArgumentException: Application tried to present modal view controller on itself

Answer (score 6):

**Application not running**

When app is in closed state you should check for launch option in `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions`

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {

    let storyBoard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)

    var viewController = UIViewController() 

    if (launchOptions?[UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey.remoteNotification] as? NSDictionary) != nil {
        viewController = storyBoard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "storyboardIdentifier") // user tap notification
    }else{
        viewController = storyBoard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "storyboardIdentifier") // User not tap notificaiton
    }
    self.window?.rootViewController = viewController
    self.window?.makeKeyAndVisible()
}
```

**Application in Foreground state** Here you can redirect on specific viewcontroller

```
func userNotificationCenter(_ center: UNUserNotificationCenter,
                                didReceive response: UNNotificationResponse,
                                withCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping () -> Void) {
        let userInfo = response.notification.request.content.userInfo

        // Print full message.
        print(userInfo)

        let storyBoard: UIStoryboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
        let presentViewController = storyBoard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "storyboardIdentifier") as! YourViewController

        presentViewController.yourDict = userInfo //pass userInfo data to viewController
        self.present(presentViewController, animated: true, completion: nil)

        completionHandler()
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You have to implement two methods for handling the notification, one for when the app is in the background, and the other for when the app has been shut down and is not running.

Inside your `AppDelegate`, implement the `application(_:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:) -> Bool` method. This is for when the app is not running:

```swift
func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey : Any]?) -> Bool {
    if let notificationData = launchOptions?[.remoteNotification] {
        // Use this data to present a view controller based
        // on the type of notification received
    }
    return true
}
```

When your app is in the background, you need to implement the `userNotificationCenter(_:didReceive:withCompletionHandler:)` method:

```swift
func userNotificationCenter(_ center: UNUserNotificationCenter, didReceive response: UNNotificationResponse, withCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping () -> Void) {
        let notificationData = response.notification.request.content.userInfo
        // Use this data to present a view controller based
        // on the type of notification received
        completionHandler()
    }
```